# Add image in Datatable of LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am trying to add image to a datatable and i know that we need to use custom types. I am using this [blog](https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/show-image-in-lightning-web-component-data-table/) as reference. I have pretty much followed the blog but cant seem to get the images to display. I am pretty sure there something very small i am missing here.

Here are the code

imageControl.html

```
<template>
  <img src={url} alt={altText} class="image"/>
</template>
```

imagecontrol.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class ImageControl extends LightningElement {
    @api url;
    @api altText;
}
```

customtable.html

```
<template>
</template>
```

customtable.js

```
import lightningDataTable from 'lightning/datatable';
import scoringImage from './scoring.html';
export default class CustomTable extends lightningDataTable {
    
    static customType ={
        image: {
            template :scoringImage
        }

    }  
}
```

scoring.html

```
<template>
         <c-image-control url={value}    alt-text="Image Not Found">    </c-image-control>
         

 </template>
```

scoring,html is part of the customtable lwc

I am using the customtype image in the lwc and here is the columns definition. pictureurl field holds the url of the images. I can see that the url is coming out correct but not the image

billinggrowth.js

```
allLabels = [{
        label: 'KPI/KPA Measurement',
        fieldName: 'kpi'
    }, {
        label: 'Scoring',
        fieldName: 'pictureurl',
        type : 'image'
    }, {
        label: 'Current',
        fieldName: 'current',
        type: 'currency'
    },
    {
        label: 'Target',
        fieldName: 'target',
        type: 'currency'
    }, {
        label: 'Gap',
        fieldName: 'gap',
        type: 'currency'
    }, {
        label: 'Percentage',
        fieldName: 'perc',
        type: 'percent'
    }];
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

**** Update *****
Here is the output i am seeing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by:

> I can see that the url is coming out correct but not the image

you mean that the URL is making it through to the rendered page then you will need to debug why the`<img src="https://..." alt=...` is not working. Otherwise see the following.

Perhaps there is a way to get the value from the field as you are doing:

```
{
    label: 'Scoring',
    fieldName: 'pictureurl',
    type : 'image'
}
```

but the mechanism that has worked for me is to go via the `typeAttributes`. (But first worth double checking that the data field names exactly match the field names you are using via some logging or debugging.)

So in the code using the table the `typeAttributes` value is pulled from a field:

```
{
    label: 'Scoring',
    fieldName: 'pictureurl',
    type : 'image',
    typeAttributes: {
        url: {
            fieldName : "pictureurl"
        },
    },
}
```

and in the `extends LightningDatatable` the `typeAttributes` name is nominated:

```
static customType ={
    image: {
        template: scoringImage,
        typeAttributes: ['url']
    }
}
```

and the cell template takes the value from the `typeAttributes` value:

```
<template>
    <c-image-control url={typeAttributes.url} alt-text="Image Not Found">
    </c-image-control>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks Keith.. I cant see the img tag at all. All it shows is the url of the image coming from class.  Let me try the typeattributes and will keep you posted

Comment: Its the same with typeattributes as well. The component doesnt seem to be rendering. The html doesnt show the img tag. Updated the question with the screenshot with the output i am seeing

Comment: Hi @Prady, That sounds like the cell is being rendered using a default type. Checking [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-table-custom-types), this name is plural `static customTypes = {` as multiple custom types can be defined. So you changing `customType` to `customTypes` may well fix the problem.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a ton. Just one more thing, its throwing an error at url={typeAttributes.url}  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url') . I think i should be able to find what the issue is but if you know something about it let me know